# Collection view with Compositional Layout not working for header view

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Trying to create `UICollectionView` using `compositionalLayout`. It's working for collection view cell but when I am trying to add header it crashes with register nib error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: SectionHeaderElementKind with identifier headerView - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Code implementation for View Controller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = customLayout()
     }

    func customLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

        let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(44)
        )
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)

        let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .absolute(40)
        )
        let sectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
            layoutSize: headerSize,
            elementKind: "SectionHeaderElementKind",
            alignment: .top
        )

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionHeader]
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView

        return cell
    }
}
```

Header View that I have created:

```
class CollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

Please help if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same value for element kind both while building the layout and registering reusable views to collection view..

Change this:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
```

To

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "SectionHeaderElementKind", withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
```